# AUDIO PROBLEM ON UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound

Suddenly, the audio of some specific applications on my ubuntu subdivision (actually all except sounds system and test sounds) stopped working while the sound system gave me no problem, as well as the Windows subdivision. I already tried to update drivers, or the operative system itself to Ubuntu 18.04, but it didn't change anything. So, I was forced to format my OS and reinstall Ubuntu 16.04. After some months, the same problem reappeared.
I know this question has already been asked (more than once) but no answer has ever been given.
Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: its not an answer - since this Ubuntu windows subsystem is very new and limited in functionality (and buggy) I suggest you bite the bullet and delete it and install Ubuntu the normal way - as a dual boot or even just reformat entire computer and install ubuntu as the only OS on box ... of course this is where having a junk development laptop laying around to install Ubuntu onto is very handy --- you can buy a cheap used Dell laptop on ebay.com just make sure it has sufficient RAM

Comment: Thank you, but I think I explained the situation badly: the system IS in dual boot, the two partitions are completely (theoretically) independent.

Comment: look at https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/   just ignore its second method

Comment: Thanks again, I've already tried everything in that guide but still, no audio except from the sound test :(
Edit: moreover the icon tray of audio disappeared and settings have changed after reinstalling pulseaudio.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after searching for days a hint from Scott Stensland unlocked the problem:

In this article he suggested ( https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/ ) the last procedure is about changing the file via:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

and to change from **RUN=yes** to **RUN=no**

**IMPORTANT:**

In my case *it was already set to "no"* and - just give it a shot - I changed it to "yes". When nothing happened I went back to "no" and it solved the problem.

Can't say why but it did, hope this might help other people.